# Changing Indirect Speech to Direct Speech

Tags: reported-speech

Changing the following from indirect to direct speech, including the reporting verb and appropriate punctuation.

1. > Indirect : Jean said that she had lost her shoes.
   >   **Direct: Jean said, "I have lost my shoes."**
2. > Indirect: Fred insisted that he would be driving his own car in the rally.
   >   **Direct: "I will be driving my car in the rally", Fred insisted.**
3. > Indirect: Sally shouted that she didn't want to go to the dentist.
   >   **Direct: Sally shouted, "I don't want to go to the dentist."**

Did I get it right?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You got it. If you need more info, check out [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech) about indirect and direct speech.